# Is there an algorithm to filter out sentence fragments?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have in a database thousands of sentences (highlights from kindle books) and some of them are sentence fragments (e.g. "You can have the nicest, most") which I am trying to filter out.

As per some definition I found, `a sentence fragment is missing either its subject or its main verb`.

I tried to find some kind of sentence fragment algorithm but without success.

But anyway in the above example, I can see the subject (`You`) and the verb (`have`) but it still doesn't look like a full sentence to me.

I thought about restricting on the length (like excluding string whose length is < than 30) but I don't think it's a good idea.

Any suggestion on how you would do it?

Comment: Do you want to determine if an english sentence is grammatically correct ?

Comment: For a really good solution, share the corpus of data you're working with (or a representative fragment of it).

Language is messy and English is messier, but sentences typically start with a capital letter and end with a period, question mark, or exclamation mark. You could use that as a first pass, and refine it based on the false positives and negatives that it produces.

E.g., the 'E.' that starts this sentence isn't a sentence but the naive rule above would indicate it is, so refinements are needed.